# Primeng accordion not maintaining the default state

Tags: accordion, primeng

When using primeng accordion in a p-dialog with multiple option, when a tab is opened and dialog is closed and again we open dialog the tan is open stii, it is not maintaining the default state as all the tabs closed though when making selected as false when opening dialog.

When using collapse all and expand all it is working when all tabs open collapse all is working but when one tab is open, the collapse all link doesn't close the opened tab.

Comment: I have similar problem and I've created a bug: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9453